# Capifony rollback doesnt works

Tags: symfony, ssh, capistrano, capifony

**My Capifony setup works... I can deploy multiple versions...**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\example>cap deploy
--> Updating code base with remote_cache strategy
--> Creating cache directory................................
--> Creating symlinks for shared directories................
--> Creating symlinks for shared files......................
--> Normalizing asset timestamps............................
--> Downloading Composer....................................
--> Installing Composer dependencies........................
--> Dumping all assets to the filesystem....................
--> Warming up cache........................................
--> Clear controllers.......................................
--> Successfully deployed!
```

**The problem is the `cap deploy:rollback` function.**

**I got this error:**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\example>cap deploy:rollback
failed: "sh -c 'cd /srv/www/example && false dump-autoload --optimize'" on 192.168.178.102
```

**Thats the `Capfile`**

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace) # cap2 differentiator

require 'capifony_symfony2'
load 'app/config/deploy'
```

**Thats the `deploy.rb`**

```
set   :application,   "ExampleProject"
set   :deploy_to,     "/srv/www/example"
set   :domain,        "example.org"

set   :scm,           :git
set   :repository,    "git@gitlab.example.org:www/project.git"

server "192.168.178.102", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

set   :use_sudo,      false
set   :keep_releases, 3
set   :deploy_via,    :remote_cache

# Symfony2
set :shared_files,        ["app/config/parameters.yml"]
set :shared_children,     [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads", "vendor"]
set :use_composer, true
set :dump_assetic_assets, true

# SSH
set :user, "www-data"
set :git_enable_submodules, 1
```

Comment: Were you able to find the solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: No i tried a newer version :

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify that composer is installed or [install it](https://getcomposer.org/download/) manually. Provide path to it in `deploy.rb` like `set :composer_bin, "/usr/bin/composer"`
2. Enable more verbose output by adding `logger.level = Logger::DEBUG` to get more details.

Comment: Why "--> Installing Composer dependencies" (vendor installation) works and the rollback doesnt?? I'll test your tips later.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work properly (wrong permission, wrong destination, etc), so enabling logging should reveal it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem you were having. After investigating a bit I found out that path to composer was being set up for some reason. I added the path of composer in my `deploy.rb` and it worked. So add the following to your `deploy.rb`

```
set :composer_bin, "/usr/bin/composer"
```

Answer (score -1):

The rollback task doesn't work/dumps an error using capifony 2.5 onwards, issue open: https://github.com/everzet/capifony/issues/511